# how to get user prompts in Intellij idea for user inputs?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

For a simple Java application, I pass the program environment in Eclipse as follows:

```
-source src/main/resources/foobar.xml -id ${string_prompt:projectID:myUniqueID} ${string_prompt:environment:QA}
```

In this example,  Eclipse will first user prompt dialog to enter projectID (with default value filled in as myUniqueID). After clicking ok, user is prompted with another dialog to enter environment (with default value QA).

how can I get the user prompt in Intellij Idea?

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent feature in IntelliJ IDEA. You can write a plugin that would ask the user to enter this information when starting a run configuration of a particular type.